# ROS (Robot Operating System) for elementary OS Loki

Tags: release-loki, software-installation, repositories

Is there any way to install ROS on Elementary OS Loki?

I found on the internet a tutorial step by step for Freya, but I only managed to have installable packages with dependency problems :/

Comment: What is ROS? If [this](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu#kinetic.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Sources.Configure_your_Ubuntu_repositories) is ROS, can you try that guide? It should work since Loki is based on Xenial

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Unfortunately when I try this guide it returns me an error while installing ros-kinetic-desktop-full - no package error.

Comment: Check what packages are avaliable with `apt-cache search ros-kinetic `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the tutorial suggested by Maccer:

```
# Setup your sources.list
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
# Set up your keys
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 5523BAEEB01FA116
# Install the package(s) wanted.
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem just following the shadow-fixed instructions and changing in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list ros for ros-shadow-fixed. After that when I install ros-kinetic-desktop-full (not ros-kinetic-my-just-released-package!) it does not give me error anymore.

Comment: You should edit this (or the other) answer so that it includes the steps you actually have to do for future reference and accept it